Disable desktop browser's autocomplete pop up
In the newer version of Chrome browsers they added an extremely annoying pop-up window with words suggestion. It distracts me and annoys me to the point that it is driving me crazy and I can't find how to disable it.
I'm attaching a picture just to make it clearer what I'm talking about, I need desperately help to disable it.


That looks like the Windows text suggestions box to me. If you're on Windows 10 or 11, check Settings > Devices > Typing > Hardware Keyboard > "Show text suggestions as I type" and turn it off

